# SQL Server Management Studio 18 - Taking long time to generate script

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, create-table, azure-synapse

I have created a table in SQL Server 2014 (v12.0 - dedicated SQL pool) with no partitions using SQL Server Management Studio v16.0.

Using an automated script, created right values hourly partitions for 4 months i.e., 2880 partitions.

Now I would like to view the create script for it.

I tried right clicking on the table > script table as > Create to > New script. But this approach is taking forever to return a script
Instead of new script I tried saving it to file on local disk but even that is taking long time

[image]

Why is this taking too long and what is a better approach to get the script faster?

PS: the DW version doesn't support partition functions and partition schemes so had to create partitions directly on table

Comment: My guess is the underlying query to retrieve the meta-data is slow. Try [updating system table statistics](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/).

Answer (score 0):

*Here is some workaround

1. By configuring a proxy server to allow access to crl.microsoft.com from your server
2. By Configuring your firewall to return a failure status quickly when it blocks access to the crl.microsoft.com website
3. And disabling the checks for certificate revocation.*

*From your browser, open the Internet Options dialog,* go to the Advanced Page, and un-check the `Check for publisher's certificate revocation` checkbox.

[image]

And generating the script to the clipboard will takes time. Instead try with `New Query Editor Window`

[image]

And also by using object explorer, as shown below.

[image]

[image]

*For more information, please refer this* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/dtjones/sql-server-management-studio-startup-time) and [tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/52/sql-server-management-studio/)